# In Nautilus is there hot-key to the side-pane's drop-down mode-selection list (Place, Tree, etc)?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

In Nautilus, I sometimes want to change the `mode` of the `side-pane` (Tree, Places, etc).

This can be done via the a mouse click on the drop button at the top of the side-pane.
...but there is no hot-key/accelerator-key to quickly display this drop-list.

I usually prefer the keyboard for basic navigation, and this lack of simple keyboard navigation is a pain in the proverbial.

If there were even a menu item to jump across to the side-pane, it wouldn't be such a pain (bad pun)... and I could just set the menu-item's accelerator key... but there isn't such a menu item!

Can I create a menu-item for this particlar chore?
or, is there already a hot-key for this?
(Jumping directly across to the side-pane would be enough. Dropping the list is ideal)

Ctrl+Tab does some sort of navigation, but it seems to stop at every control on its route, and this results in a varying number of whistle-stops, depending on the state of the rest of the window (eg. Extra pane, Expanded trees...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a hotkey, but:

**If your selection is in the nautilus main window, "tab-tab-space" should drop down the list.**

I'd imagine there's some sort of linux keybinding widget that would bind this keyboard combo to something more useful, like "control+`" or whatever you wanted; however, I do not know what that utility is.

Comment: m ... Yes, tab-tab does get me there *most* of the time, so thanks for that. I'll use that for now... However, getting back is another issue... It seems that nautilus (and many other programs these days) are written in a mouse-centric way... The original well thought out paradigm of equal functionality for both mouse and keyboard seems to have gone by the wayside, somewhat. C'est la vie! Nautilus is still a great program, and I'll just have to work with it, and perhaps around it with xmacro

Comment: ... my previous message got sent prematurely... here is the last part:  ... and perhaps work around it with xmacro and xbindkeys... but I'll probably just use it as-is, now that I know that there's (probably) no single key option.

Comment: I agree about the creeping 'mouse-centricness' of modern applications. =) ... I'm a big believer in intuitive design, but also a fanatic for efficiency of use, which puts me in an odd position between the two paradigms. I want to get as close from direct brain-to-computer translation as possible, which is possible with a finely honed set of keyboard shorcuts wired into your nervous system, but we'll probably not live to see the days of functional and ubiquitous thought-controlled computers. ...sigh  /end techno-dreams

Answer (score 1):

I've also gone looking for this as a possible configuration setting under metacity (gconf-editor>applications>nautilus", but found no such thing.

I did, however, find something useful:

```
gconf-editor /apps/nautilus/preferences/side_pane_view
```

This sets the default view for the side panel in new windows.

This is a promising lead, but no cigar.

Comment: This is a good bit of info... It does what it does, and is useful, but I couldn't wrangle anything more out of it... so, as you said, "no cigar", but you can have your choice of a GI-Joe or an Arnie(Arnold?)... Thanks.

Comment: 'you can have your choice of a GI-Joe or an Arnie(Arnold)'  lol.